# How to combine Z-Transparency and Mask Transparency in BI

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I have a plane, in front of a cube, with a texture used for alpha.

[image: Origin]

Now i like to use the BI Mask-Transparency to (alpha) hide everything behind the white areas. The black areas should be complete transparent

How can i mix this settings:
[image: mask-transparency]
[image: z-transparency]

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this for the BI, but would you be willing to do this in cycles? It is easy in cycles.

Comment: That wont help me. I'll render a volumetric fog and than combine it with my already done cycles scene.